# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

i see some error in console

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://Orchard.Club/Member/List"

when i try to copy this link and run it . it says "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

**ControlList View**

```
@{            
Script.Require("jQuery");
Script.Require("jQueryUI");
Script.Require("flexigrid");

Style.Include("Common.css");
Style.Include("flexigrid.css");
Style.Include("flexigrid.pack.css");
}



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.AntiForgeryTokenOrchard()

<table id="jobListing" style="display: none"></table>

}


@using (Script.Foot())
{     
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jobListing').flexigrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("List", "Member")',
            formData: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: '@Html.AntiForgeryTokenValueOrchard()'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel: [
                {
                    display: 'Caption',
                    name: 'Caption',
                    width: 180,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                }, {
                    display: 'Name',
                    name: 'Name',
                    width: 180,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                }, ]
        });
    });        

</script>

}
```

**Controller**

```
         public ActionResult ControlList()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult List()
    {            
        List<Controls> controls = new List<Controls>();

        controls.Add(new Controls() { Id = 1, Caption = "1", Name = "2", ControlType = "textbox" });
        controls.Add(new Controls() { Id = 2, Caption = "1", Name = "2", ControlType = "textbox" });
        controls.Add(new Controls() { Id = 3, Caption = "1", Name = "2", ControlType = "textbox" });

        return CreateFlexiJson(controls.ToList(), 1,1);            
    }

    private JsonResult CreateFlexiJson(IEnumerable<Controls> items, int page, int total)
    {
        return Json(
                new
                {
                    page,
                    total,
                    rows =
                        items
                        .Select(x =>
                            new
                            {
                                id = x.Id,
                                // either use GetPropertyList(x) method to get all columns 
                                cell = new object[] { x.Caption, x.Name, x.ControlType, x.Id }
                            })
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I have modified the code now i am not getting this error but call to controller is not working. i checked console and it says this error

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" "localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Orchard.Club/Member/List"

Comment: Attach a debugger and find out exactly what's going on. You can also look at the logs under app_data\logs. 500 is only telling you that something wrong happened on the server.

Comment: Don't you want to return the ViewModel itself? Why are you creating a ViewModel and then just return its List?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a get?

Comment: please see my modified code. i have made some changes. i see some error in console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Orchard.Club/Member/List" when i try to copy this link and run it . it says "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."